# Postgresql jsonb_set function does not exists

Tags: postgresql

I want to use jsonb_set function but I got this error:

```
function jsonb_set(jsonb, jsonb, boolean) does not exist
  Info: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 28
```

here is my query:

```
UPDATE holidays SET logs = jsonb_set('[{"a":"foo"}]'::jsonb, '{}'::jsonb, true) WHERE id = 1;
```

€:

Replaced function with jsonb_insert (thats what I need) but still got error also with path:

```
malformed array literal: "[{"a":"foo"}]"
  Detail: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
  Position: 41
```

code:

```
UPDATE holidays SET logs = jsonb_insert('[{"a":"foo"}]'::jsonb[], '{"b": "hello"}'::jsonb, '0', true) WHERE id = 1;
```

€: Solved it with logs = logs || '{"a": "foo"}'::jsonb

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @Schwern version 15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed incorrect arguments to `jsonb_set`. [The correct arguments are](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)...

```
jsonb_set ( target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_if_missing boolean ] ) → jsonb
```

You're missing the path.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I got still error. Look at my code above, I edited

Comment: I have a array of json objects in my logs column. And I want to add a new object to the array

Comment: @serverz You're confusing a JSON array with a PostgreSQL array. It doesn't matter if the JSON contains an array, it's still `jsonb`. `'[{"a":"foo"}]'::jsonb`. You don't need the casts, PostgreSQL will figure it out. And, like `jsonb_set`, it takes a path as `text[]`. `jsonb_insert ( target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, insert_after boolean ] )`. So something like `select jsonb_insert('[{"a":"foo"}]', '{0}', '{"b": "hello"}', true)` will result in `[{"a": "foo"}, {"b": "hello"}]`. `{0}` says to insert in the first element of the array.

Comment: @serverz Be sure to consult the examples [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).